# Show/Hide webview issue

Tags: java, android, flash, webview

I'm working in an application that has in the same view a set of buttons and a web view(GONE), when the app starts it shows only the buttons from where at a click it shows the web view and loads a url (the layout where the buttons are is set to GONE) that contains a flash media player and a single button that when is click it makes the web view invisible again and shows the first layout that contains the buttons to be able to choose a different website, the problem is that when the web view goes invisible the flash media players stays stuck on the screen and blocks the buttons, how can I fix this? It would be ok if the media player stays behind the buttons but I cannot find an answer, any help will be highly appreciated, Thank you.

Update with Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Web 1" android:id="@+id/buttonWeb1"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonWeb2" android:text="Web 2"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Web 3" android:id="@+id/buttonWeb3"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonBack" android:text="Back to Buttons"></Button>
    <WebView android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/webView"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the main Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class FlashejemploActivity extends Activity {

WebView wv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

    final LinearLayout buttons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    final LinearLayout webV = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    final Button   web1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonWeb1);
    final Button   web2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonWeb2);
    final Button   web3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonWeb3);
    final Button   back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);

      wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView );
      wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
      wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      wv.setInitialScale(1);
      wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


      final Activity PActivity = this;
      wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
        {

        PActivity.setTitle("Cargando....");
        PActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); 

        if(progress == 100)
               PActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
          }
        });

    webV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     web1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                wv.loadUrl("http://los40.com.mx/Player.htm");
            }});
     web2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                wv.loadUrl("http://www.beat1009.com.mx/n2/paginas/radio.php");
            }});
     web3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                wv.loadUrl("http://besame.com.mx/Player.htm");
            }});
     back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }});

}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code associated with this question

Comment: @ Kevin, I'm sorry for the delay but here it is I just update the question with the code I'm using. if you try it you will see what I mean. Thanks

Comment: @zvzej Have you found any solution. I too have same problem.

Comment: No, I haven't found a way to fix this.

Comment: Did you try calling `view.bringToFront(); parent.requestLayout(); parent.invalidate();`? Also you may need to change your parent layout to `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: BTW, using fragments seem a better solution today.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while but I have just solved a similar problem by getting the webview to empty

```
wv.loadUrl("about:blank");
```