# Unable to hide webview after url loads

Tags: android, webview

I am using the following code to hide the webview if a url ends with a particular string.

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith("index.asp")) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Login successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            webview.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        }
    }
 });
```

but the webview still remains if the url ends with index.asp( for example "http://abc.def/index.asp")

Comment: why you are hiding webview `onPageFinished`? Check if the url ends with that string. If not open webview, otherwise dont show it at all.

Comment: Try to wrap webview by LinearLayout or FragmentView. Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942219/show-hide-webview-issue ?

Comment: debug and test if the condition you are checking is satisfying.

Comment: @hrskrs I have a login page which is loaded into the webview when the app starts and when user enter their details,another url opens containing index.asp, but I don't want to display the content of that urlmHence hiding the webview.

Comment: @rj yes the condition is satisfied,I have checked it with a toast.

Comment: @toadalskiii do you namely want to use webview? try to use jsoup library

Comment: try this `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){ view.setVisibility(view.GONE);`

Comment: @trololo jsoup is static lib,It can't allow dynamic process like login.

Comment: @RohanPawar It can't be used,even if it worked,then the initial login page would also not visible.

Comment: @toadalskiii of couse, you can do everything you want . add custom edit text forms in order to login.

Comment: @trololo thats the different scenario,but for now I just want to use webviewclient.

Comment: @toadalskiii ok. you decision. did you read the link I wrote before?

Comment: @trololo I have read the link referred,but it loads a blank page with zoom controls and after login I also want to display a toast for successful login which is not shown when I load blank page.

Comment: Try `url.contains("index.asp");`

Answer (score 3):

instead of:

```
webview.setVisibility(view.GONE);
```

use:

```
view.setVisibility(view.GONE);
```

Comment: Maybe if you post more code we can help you, otherwise a bad solution can be to wrap `WebView` in a `FrameView` and if it satisfies your condition show that `frameview` othervise hide it`(Visibility.GONE)`

Answer (score 0):

As discussed here [How to listen for a Webview finishing loading a URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android/5172952#5172952~) sometimes webview url will redirect the call backs. it means onPageFinished() will call [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282892/android-webview-onpagefinished-called-twice) (more than one time). If it is the case you should check the redirect states aswell for your url call backs in `onPageFinished()` method

```
boolean loadingFinished = true;
boolean redirect = false;

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
       if (!loadingFinished) {
          redirect = true;
       }

   loadingFinished = false;
   view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
   return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
        loadingFinished = false;
        //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE  
    }

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       if(!redirect){
          loadingFinished = true;
       }

       if(loadingFinished && !redirect){
         //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
                 if (url.endsWith("index.asp")) {
                    webview.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                  }

       } else{
          redirect = false; 
       }

    }
});
```

Hope it will helps

Comment: how could I use this - string url="", the url is the one fetched by webview and it is dynamic.

Comment: did you printed your url's ? is it correctly loading and getting back in your onPageFinished() method ?

Comment: I have tried  if(url.contains("index.asp")) but in the if condition the toast is getting printed successfully but webview is not hidden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88540/discussion-between-king-of-masses-and-toadalskiii).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the other library if you do not want to draw the content on a view.
For instane, [jsoup library](http://jsoup.org/download).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check by clearing animation if you have set any since i had same problem with layout not disappearing on setVisibility(View.Gone).. Try this

```
webview.clearAnimation();
```

it helped me.